# Caching issue with webpack-dev-server

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm having some issues when running the webpack-dev-server. Whenever I save a file, and changes are compiled, they are not being reflected in the browser. (No errors in command line)

I'm running the following command:

`webpack-dev-server --progress --color`

However, if I run `webpack` every time I have a change, this is reflected in my browser.

I run Chrome on my Mac (latest v. of OSX), and I've enabled the "Disable cache while devtools is open" option. Needless to say, but hey - you never know, I have my DevTools open.. :)

Am I missing a simple step here?

Comment: are you appending the watch directory to the webpack-dev-server ie. webpack-dev-server --progress --color /your-project-to-watch ?

Comment: @4m1r No, I haven't done that. Watching a pluralsight course, and the author gets it working. (Not to say that his way is the correcty way).

I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To disable cache, I used [Cache-Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) header in webpack config.

```
devServer: {
  headers: {
    'Cache-Control': 'no-store',
  },
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I was using `dist/app.js` file in my html and not `app.js` that generated by webpack-dev-server.

Using this in my html solved the issue:

```
<script src="vendor.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to point my script tags directly at the webpack-dev-server with the full URL, like so:

```
<script src="http://localhost:8080/vendor.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:8080/app.bundle.min.js"></script>
```